# Socket Python-Server and Java - Client in android studio where java is not able to connect to the python server

Tags: java, python, android, sockets

I have successfully built a python server which even works but when java from android studio tries to connect to it fails with whole bunch of errors. I have understood that it fails while creating a new socket object but why that I don't know.

This is Java client, see at the end of the code particularly for the issue where I have created new Socket object:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionTextDetector;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Button btnRecognize;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    static EditText ET_ShowRecognized;
    String locality;
    private Intent intent;
    private String ET_ShowRecognizedText;
    private String ProcessingText;
    //private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    //Geocoder geocoder;
    Python py;
    PyObject pyobj;
    PyObject obj;
    String currentDate;
    String currentTime;
    static TextToSpeech tts;
    Uri imageURI;
    ContentValues contentValues;
    Intent cameraIntent;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    Image mediaImage;
    FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage;
    static Bitmap  imageBitmap;
    FirebaseVisionTextDetector textDetector;
    String imgText;
    Intent CameraIntent;
    static Thread sent;
    static Thread receive;
    static Socket socket;
    InputStreamReader in;
    BufferedReader bf;
    String ServerOutput;
    PrintWriter writer;
    String ServerInput;


    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "ClickableViewAccessibility", "MissingPermission"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


        ET_ShowRecognized = findViewById(R.id.ET_ShowRecognized);
        btnRecognize = findViewById(R.id.btnRecognize);
        /*fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                Location location = task.getResult();
                if(location != null){

                    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try {

                        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                        locality = address.get(0).getLocality();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        if(!Python.isStarted()){

            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));

        }
        py = Python.getInstance();
        pyobj = py.getModule("WolframAlpha");
        obj = pyobj.callAttr("main", locality);*/

        tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

                }
                tts.speak("Hi you successfully ran me.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                tts.speak("Seems good to meet you.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            }
        });


        //currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //textToSpeech.speak("Hi! I am your personal assistant. Today date is something something ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        //Speak("Today's weather forecast for the current location is " + obj.toString());


        intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                ArrayList<String> mathches = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

                if (mathches != null) {
                    ET_ShowRecognized.setText(mathches.get(0));
                    process();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
        });


        btnRecognize.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        speechRecognizer.stopListening();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ET_ShowRecognized.setText(null);
                        ET_ShowRecognized.setText("Listening...");
                        speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
   

    public void process() {

        ProcessingText = ET_ShowRecognized.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

        if(ProcessingText.contains("hello")) {

            tts.speak("Hi! I hope all is well.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("hi")){

            tts.speak("Hello! Nice to meet you.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("your name")){

            tts.speak("My name is assistant.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("recognise text")){

            tts.speak("Opening Camera.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("bye")){

            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("current temperature")){

            /*try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.43.203",12345);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            sent = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        while(true){


                            ServerOutput = bf.readLine().toString();
                            MainActivity.tts.speak(ServerOutput, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                            MainActivity.ET_ShowRecognized.setText(ServerOutput);

                        }
                    }

                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            sent.start();
            try {
                sent.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            recieve_data();

        }else {

            tts.speak(ProcessingText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        CameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(CameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // display error state to the user
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            detectTextFromImage();
        }
    }

    private void detectTextFromImage() {

        firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap);
        textDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionTextDetector();
        textDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {

                //speakTextFromImage(firebaseVisionText);
                getImgText(firebaseVisionText);


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                tts.speak("Something went wrong. Please try again later or try with another image.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                ET_ShowRecognized.setText("Something went wrong. Please try again later or try with another image.");
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void getImgText(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText){

        List<FirebaseVisionText.Block> blockList = firebaseVisionText.getBlocks();
        if(blockList.size() == 0) {

            tts.speak("I think this image contains no text.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            ET_ShowRecognized.setText("I think this image contains no text.");

        }else{

            for(FirebaseVisionText.Block block : firebaseVisionText.getBlocks()){

                imgText = block.getText().toString();
                tts.speak("The text in the image is as follows : " + imgText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                ET_ShowRecognized.setText("The text in the image is as follows : " + imgText);

            }
        }
    }

    public void recieve_data(){


        ServerInput = "Java client is successfully connected with the server ";
        BackgroundTask bt = new BackgroundTask();
            bt.execute(ServerInput);
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
            try{

                String message = voids[0];
                socket = new Socket("myIP", 24224);
                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(message);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                socket.close();


            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

This is my python server code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket successfully created")

try:
    port = 24224
    s.bind(("", port))
    print("socket binded to %s" %(port))
except socket.error as err:
    print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' .format(err))
    
s.listen(10)

while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    print("Client : " + message)
    conn.close()
```

Now the run view in the android studio:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.maitreyastudio.ai, PID: 17690
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maitreyastudio.ai/com.maitreyastudio.ai.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1318)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:340)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:548)
       at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:440)
       at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:223)
       at com.maitreyastudio.ai.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:127)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6712)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace I see that you are trying to connect on the ui thread which
is causing the crash. You need to move the connection logic in to its own thread

Here is a link to the documentation that will help you
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Threads

try this for main activity

`import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionTextDetector;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Button btnRecognize;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    static EditText ET_ShowRecognized;
    String locality;
    private Intent intent;
    private String ET_ShowRecognizedText;
    private String ProcessingText;
    //private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    //Geocoder geocoder;
    Python py;
    PyObject pyobj;
    PyObject obj;
    String currentDate;
    String currentTime;
    static TextToSpeech tts;
    Uri imageURI;
    ContentValues contentValues;
    Intent cameraIntent;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    Image mediaImage;
    FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage;
    static Bitmap  imageBitmap;
    FirebaseVisionTextDetector textDetector;
    String imgText;
    Intent CameraIntent;
    static Thread sent;
    static Thread receive;
    static Socket socket;
    InputStreamReader in;
    BufferedReader bf;
    String ServerOutput;
    PrintWriter writer;
    String ServerInput;



    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "ClickableViewAccessibility", "MissingPermission"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


        ET_ShowRecognized = findViewById(R.id.ET_ShowRecognized);
        btnRecognize = findViewById(R.id.btnRecognize);








        /*fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                Location location = task.getResult();
                if(location != null){

                    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try {

                        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                        locality = address.get(0).getLocality();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        ;
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        if(!Python.isStarted()){

            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));

        }
        py = Python.getInstance();
        pyobj = py.getModule("WolframAlpha");
        obj = pyobj.callAttr("main", locality);*/

        tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

                }
                tts.speak("Hi you successfully ran me.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                tts.speak("Seems good to meet you.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            }
        });


        //currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //textToSpeech.speak("Hi! I am your personal assistant. Today date is something something ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        //Speak("Today's weather forecast for the current location is " + obj.toString());


        intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                ArrayList<String> mathches = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

                if (mathches != null) {

                    ET_ShowRecognized.setText(mathches.get(0));
                    process();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
        });


        btnRecognize.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        speechRecognizer.stopListening();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ET_ShowRecognized.setText(null);
                        ET_ShowRecognized.setText("Listening...");
                        speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });


    }

   

    public void process() {

        ProcessingText = ET_ShowRecognized.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

        if(ProcessingText.contains("hello")) {

            tts.speak("Hi! I hope all is well.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("hi")){

            tts.speak("Hello! Nice to meet you.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("your name")){

            tts.speak("My name is assistant.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("recognise text")){

            tts.speak("Opening Camera.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("bye")){

            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
        else if(ProcessingText.contains("current temperature")){

            sendTemp();
            recieve_data();

        }else {

            tts.speak(ProcessingText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

        }


    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        CameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(CameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // display error state to the user
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            detectTextFromImage();
        }

    }

    private void detectTextFromImage() {

        firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap);
        textDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionTextDetector();
        textDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {

                //speakTextFromImage(firebaseVisionText);
                getImgText(firebaseVisionText);


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                tts.speak("Something went wrong. Please try again later or try with another image.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                ET_ShowRecognized.setText("Something went wrong. Please try again later or try with another image.");
            }
        });



    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void getImgText(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText){

        List<FirebaseVisionText.Block> blockList = firebaseVisionText.getBlocks();
        if(blockList.size() == 0) {

            tts.speak("I think this image contains no text.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            ET_ShowRecognized.setText("I think this image contains no text.");

        }else{

            for(FirebaseVisionText.Block block : firebaseVisionText.getBlocks()){

                imgText = block.getText().toString();
                tts.speak("The text in the image is as follows : " + imgText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                ET_ShowRecognized.setText("The text in the image is as follows : " + imgText);


            }
        }



    }
    public void recieve_data(){


        ServerInput = "Java client is successfully connected with the server ";
        BackgroundTask bt = new BackgroundTask();
            bt.execute(ServerInput);

    }

    public void sendTemp(){
        new TempBackgroundTask().execute();
    }


    class TempBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("myIP",12345);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            sent = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        while(true){


                            ServerOutput = bf.readLine().toString();
                            publishProgress(ServerOutput);

                        }
                    }

                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            sent.start();
            try {
                sent.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

          MainActivity.tts.speak(text[0], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            MainActivity.ET_ShowRecognized.setText(text[0]);
        }
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
            try{

                String message = voids[0];
                socket = new Socket("192.168.43.203", 24224);
                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(message);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                socket.close();


            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {


        super.onResume();
    }
}`